# How to set the origin of whole canvas to bottom left in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am working on canvas and using fabric js as the library for drawing and interaction.

How can I set the coordinate of the complete canvas to bottom left. I am not asking about the Origin of the object. But the origin of the canvas from where it draws the diagram. By default, the canvas draws from top-left. I want to shift it to bottom-left

In canvas, I can do that easily by specifying `translate` and `scale` on the canvas context but I am not able to figure out the same for fabric js.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/pull/4624)?